# Pass variable in url_for to Python function

Tags: python, flask

I have Python/Flask project that displays a button called Tickets at the end of a list row.  I am trying to pass **proj_id** in Jinja syntax to a Python function 'tix(proj_id)' where it will be used as an input to a SQL Alchemy query.   The value **project.id** is an integer that is not null.

HTML:

`<td class="text-end"><a href="{{ url_for('tix', proj_id=project.id) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Tickets</a></td>`

Python:

```
def tix(proj_id):
    tickets = Ticket.query.where(Ticket.project_id == proj_id)
    return render_template('ticket.html', allticket=tickets)
```

Clicking the Tickets button creates this error message:
*TypeError: tix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'proj_id'*

Is the syntax incorrect or is there some other issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you add a variable to your route? like this :

```
@app.route("/ticket/<int:proj_id>")
def tix(proj_id):
    tickets = Ticket.query.where(Ticket.project_id == proj_id)
    return render_template('ticket.html', allticket=tickets)
```